# Freeform Pro 4.0.12 IE8 and IE9 comparability issues

Tags: solspace-freeform

Using EE v2.6.1 MSM
Freeform Pro v4.0.12

When login EE CP using IE8 or IE9, I'm getting compatibility issue, form listing and entries listing does not show like in Firefox or Chrome.  Also when tried to filter entries by search or by filter selections, it does not filter at all.

Is this an error on FreeForm Pro or FreeForm Pro does not work on IE browsers? Please advise and thank you.

Comment: Could you possibly include a screenshot of the issue you are experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

IE8 cannot support CSS3 styles, so it gets a plain look because its not a good browser. IE9+ supports the advanced visual styles so it should look the same as Chrome and Firefox there.

I was able to reproduce the entry filtering bug you mentioned in ie8.

IE's JavaScript interpreter fails on some keywords. In this instance 'export'. On line 600 of ./system/expressionengine/third_party/freeform/views/entries.html, change:

```
'title'     : langItems.export,
```

to:

```
'title'     : langItems['export'],
```

Making this change fixed the errors for me in IE.

This will be fixed in the next release of Freeform, 4.1.3.